Dotnet6 on linux is recognized in terminal but not by unity and other programs
I switched to POP!os (ubuntu based linux distro). Visual studio isn't avaliable on linux and I have to use vscode. It's good and all but I can't manage to install dotnet6. I want dotnet6 to make unity coding easier because at the moment it doesn't give code suggestions like it did on visual studio on windows and I also want to make simple forms/console apps. I tried many things... script from official page didn't work, package manager broke unity for me completely, snap makes terminal recognize dotnet6 --version command but visual studio code and unity don't recognize dotnet6 as installed, pasting given commands on official website also doesn't help. I also get from unity some OmniSharp warning that useModernNet or smt like that should be false to avoid errors. Can someone help me?
